# What is the Logic Behind Synchronization in CQRS with Separate Storages?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, event-driven, eventstoredb, event-stream

When using CQRS, we operate with two separate storages. How exactly is the sync operation performed in this context?

Let's say I used an event store database for the Write storage and Elasticsearch for the Read side. I introduce a message broker in between (as the event store database can stream events on its own, as far as I know).

Currently, I have a single event, and to make changes in the Read storage, do I need to write a separate component? Assuming I did, as I mentioned, I now have the latest incoming event. How can I reach the last state using this single event, and how do I perform the sync?

I haven't fully grasped this topic. How and where do we obtain the last state? Does it flow through a stream instead of a single event, and does the component I mentioned find the last state through the stream? Perhaps we use snapshots or other mechanisms for performance?

Comment: You'll have far better luck on the discord on https://github.com/ddd-cqrs-es/community than attempting to have a conversation like this on SO

Answer (score 0):

Typically, between your "write storage" and your "read side" will be some automatic process for copying and transforming the information from one to the other.

Assuming that correct construction of a read model requires events *in their proper sequence*, your process will fetch sequences of events from the event store.

Using a message broker is not (generally) suitable for automatic processes that require correctly sequenced events.

It can make sense in some cases to use the message broker to *trigger* the reads of sequences of events from the event store; in common cases a polling loop (bypassing the message broker entirely) is sufficient.

(Recommended viewing: Greg Young, [Polyglot Data 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv2dKtPq0ME)).